# Using React-Quill with Form FormItem in antd design react

Tags: reactjs, antd, quill, ant-design-pro

Actually I want to use react-quill component as a part of antd Form.item.

```
 <ReactQuill
   ref='editor'
   onChange={this.onChange}
 />
```

Above component is react-quill basic component.
I need to use like below mentioned

```
 <Field
   label="Departure"
   placeholder="Departure"
   name="departure"
   component={}
 />
```

above `<Field />` , actually it is import props from redux form, which is, I am using in `Antd` Form as Form.Item like below

```
import {
  Form,
  Input,
} from 'antd'

const FormItem = Form.Item;

const makeField = Component => ({
  input,
  meta,
  children,
  hasFeedback,
  label,
  labelRight,
  ...rest
}) => {
  const hasError = meta.touched && meta.invalid;
  return (
    <FormItem
      {...formItemLayout}
      label={label}
      validateStatus={hasError ? 'error' : 'success'}
      hasFeedback={hasFeedback && hasError}
      help={hasError && meta.error}
    >
      <Component {...input} {...rest}>
        {children}
      </Component>
      {labelRight && (
        <span style={{ color: (rest.disabled && '#5a5a5a') || '#9e9e9e' }}>
          {labelRight}
        </span>
      )}
    </FormItem>
  );
};

export const AInput = makeField(Input);
```

Usage in Form

```
<Field
  label="Destination"
  placeholder="Destination"
  name="destination"
  component={AInput}
/>
```

As shown above, how I use `antd` `Input` in `Form.Item` and than render in `Redux-Form` `Field`. Similarly, I need to use `React-Quill` Component.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to wrap a hidden antd `<Input />` in `getFieldDecorator`. Then, render the react-quill input and use the hidden `<Input />` to manage it's state. See this example using a plain `<input />`:

```js
class Form extends React.Component {
  handleChange = e => {
    const { value } = e.target;

    this.props.form.setFieldsValue({ input: value });
  };

  render() {
    const { getFieldValue, getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form;

    return (
      <Form layout="inline">
        {/* This is a hidden antd Input used to manage form state */}
        {getFieldDecorator("input")(<Input style={{ display: "none" }} />)}

        <input
          type="text"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          value={getFieldValue("input")}
        />

        <Form.Item>
          <Button
            type="primary"
            htmlType="submit"
            onClick={() => console.log(getFieldValue("input"))}
          >
            test
          </Button>
        </Form.Item>
      </Form>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Edit qyol7omww]

Comment: Max,  I did not got your point, but anyway i did it thanks for your effort.

Comment: @MuhammadSulman and how did you do it?, please if you can share your experience

Comment: @AhmedBltagy post answer below. if it still not work than, feel free to contact.

Answer (score 0):

Install `"react-quill": "^1.3.3"` from https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-quill

I have made my one formHOC util file from where I import all form components. Similarly design this component also.

```
import ReactQuill from "react-quill"; // third party library "react-quill": "^1.3.3",

import {
  Form,
} from 'antd'; 

// customization shown below

const FormItem = Form.Item;

var formItemLayout = {
  labelCol: {
    xs: { span: 24 },
    sm: { span: 8 },
  },
  wrapperCol: {
    xs: { span: 24 },
    sm: { span: 16 },
  },
};

const makeEditorField = Component => ({
                                  input,
                                  meta,
                                  children,
                                  hasFeedback,
                                  label,
                                  labelRight,
                                  ...rest
                                }) => {
  const hasError = meta.touched && meta.invalid;
  return (
    <FormItem
      {...formItemLayout}
      label={label}
      validateStatus={hasError ? 'error' : 'success'}
      hasFeedback={hasFeedback && hasError}
      help={hasError && meta.error}
    >
      <Component {...input} {...rest}
       onBlur={(range, source, quill) => {
         input.onBlur(quill.getHTML());
       }}
      >
        {children}
      </Component>
      {labelRight && (
        <span style={{ color: (rest.disabled && '#5a5a5a') || '#9e9e9e' }}>
          {labelRight}
        </span>
      )}
    </FormItem>
  );
};

export const AEditor= makeEditorField(ReactQuill); // Export it to use other files.
```

**Usage**

```
import {AEditor} from "../../utils/formHOC";
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form/immutable';
```

```
 <Field
            label="Departure"
            placeholder="Departure"
            name="departure"
            modules={modules}
            formats={formats}
            component={AEditor}
          />
```